# dropdown menu error or ie 10 compatibility mode for ie8 bug

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, hover, internet-explorer-10, ie-compatibility-mode

I have this dropdown menu that works fine in ie 10 compatibility mode for ie 7 and ie 9, but not for ie 8, it simply won't show. So I was wondering if this is a problem that targets ie 8 but not ie 7 or if there is some sort of bug in ie 10's compatibility mode.

Could someone please check [this](http://www.proyectossocialesdirectos.org) using ie8?

It's the blue bar, below the banner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same issue. My dropdown menu is not working reliably. It kind of half works if I click the page around it, but doesn't appear all at once. If I switch to ie7 or ie9 document mode, it works fine (as it does in non-ie browsers). Really frustrating. Unfortunately, the page I'm working on includes the meta-tag that forces ie8 document mode. All indications are that this is in fact an IE10 bug. I would be delighted to hear if anyone is aware of a solution.

Comment: I resolved my issues. The dropdown/CSS was not written by me (was created by another party who I believe used the bootstrap framework). It included 
.navbar-inner {filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#3c3c3c', GradientType=0);}
in the CSS. Removing that fixed my issue and the dropdown now works fine in IE10/IE8 browser mode.